# Monitor postgres 9 queries

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

There is a postgres 9 with database `AAA` that is used by my application. I use pgadmin 4 to manage it manually.

I would like to check what queries are executed by this application on database `AAA` in real time.

I did a research about monitoring options in pgadmin in vain.

Is is possible to do that by using just pgadmin4? Or is it necessary to use another tool (if yes - what is he name of this tool)?

Comment: `select * from pg_stat_activity;`? It is not related to `pgadmin` specifically, just any tool that be able to connect to the PostgreSQL (psql for example). (explanation of this view:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)

Comment: this query show every queries that was executed by default? or should i enable someting?

Comment: Before v10, the major version of PostgreSQL is defined by the first two components.  So "postgres 9" isn't very meaningful.  9.0 is very different from 9.6.

Comment: @jjanes I use postgres 9.6

Answer (score 0):

When I point pgAdmin4 at a 9.6 server, I see a dashboard by default which shows every session (done by querying pg_stat_activity).  You can then drill down in a session to see the query.  If a query last for less time than the monitoring interval, then you might not see it if the sample is taken at the wrong time.

If that isn't acceptable, then you should probably use a logging solution (like `log_statemnt='all'`) or maybe the `pg_stat_statements` extension, rather than sample-based monitoring.  pg_stat_statements doesn't integrate with the dashboard in pgAdmin4, but you can select from the view from an SQL window just like you can run any other SQL.  I don't believe pgAdmin4 offers a built-in way to monitor the database server's log files, the way pgAdmin3 did.